# Cordova support for Android API 21

Tags: cordova, cordova-4

Does Cordova v4.2.0 support Android API 21?
When I add android platform, it adds API-19 by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can/should do it in Cordova's config file:preference:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
```

Comment: @Bharat Recheck the genrated AndroidManifest.xml file in bld folder to see if the minSdkVersion is applied or not

Comment: Yes..Checked that just now and it shows version 21 there, but the console when adding platform shows android-19 though!